# can you turn on airplay mirroring with iOS 5 objective-c code?

Tags: ipad, ios5, airplay

can you trigger airplay mirroring with iOS 5 code?

I see in the API how you can stream. Just wonder if anyone knows how to turn on and off mirroring programmically in my app on iPad2 using iOS5, or if that even is possible.

I DO see how to physically turn it on via the dock at the bottom of the screen,
so no need to post a link to the Apple demo of that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible. With a bit of luck this may change tomorrow, but it isn't something I can see apple doing. (for the same reasons as they dont allow toggling bluetooth/airplane mode/wifi etc..)